# Draw a tree or organization chart from parent child data

Tags: .net, charts, tree, draw, organization

I have parent-child information in a table with GroupID (TreeID.)

[image]

From this table I want to derive something like this:

[image]

The purpose of drawing a tree is for viewing only. The table has thousands of groupID/tree structures.

I am using the .NET platform.

How should I proceed?

```
create table parent_child (GroupID varchar(100) null,   
                           Level varchar(100) null, 
                           Name varchar(100) null,  
                           ID varchar(100) null,    
                           ParentID varchar(100) null,  
                           Top_Parent varchar(100) null)

 insert into parent_child (GroupID,Level, Name,ID,ParentID,Top_Parent) values 
     ('1234', '4', 'James', '6712', '921', '1005'), 
     ('1234', '3', 'Peter', '11', '206', '1005'),
     ('1234', '3', 'Royden', '14', '206', '1005'), 
     ('1234', '3', 'Lila', '237', '589', '1005'),
     ('1234', '3', 'Julie', '921', '589', '1005'), 
     ('1234', '2', 'Sandy', '206', '1005', '1005'), 
     ('1234', '2', 'Tom', '589', '1005', '1005'), 
     ('1234', '1', 'Sam', '1005', 'NA', '1005')
```

Comment: What platform/environment are you working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article *[A Graph Tree Drawing Control for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/LayeredTreeDraw.aspx)* (at [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)) explains how to achieve what you have in mind, both in [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) and [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight). Kudo's to the guy who made the code available - it's well written and very easy to customize.

Screenshot from The Code Project site:

[image]

You will have to write the logic to convert your table data to a compatible data structure.

I hope the article helps!