# Tree-View for Web-Applications

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-applications, treeview

what are the alternatives for navigating and managing hierarchies? Is there indeed a better way than a tree-view, or is the venerable tree-view truly the best solution to the problem? Has anyone got any links to any well implemented tree-views; i.e., those that perhaps don't try and mimic an OS tree-view? Any insight on this, or links to potential alternative solutions, would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think an idea based on the same kind of zoom-in/zoom-out features [prezi](http://prezi.com/) would be a really nice way to traverse a tree, although I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: explain more please, i opened your link but couldn't understand why you provided it ?

Comment: @Stacker: I only pointed to Prezi to give inspiration for a non-standard way to visualize a tree hierarchy. If you take a look at some of the showcase presentations, or start building your own presentation, you see that you can easily represent a "folder" by a zoom level, and by zooming further in you can examine the next level in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In some instances, a traditional organization chart is well understood by users. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667352/draw-tree-or-organization-chart-from-parent-child-data/5678907#5678907), and [SpaceTrees](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html) at [thejit.org](http://thejit.org/).